# Is def considered a closure in Scala?

Tags: scala, function, closures

I want to understand the difference between the closure declared as val and the one declared as method (with the def kyeword). What's exactly the difference between theses two functions, is the ep method a closure ?

scala > var more=10

scala > val  phi= (x:Int)=>x+more

scala >   def  ep(x:Int):Int= x+more

Comment: The "closure" term is a characteristic of function, not a a function or method itself.

Comment: Yes, but i want to know if i  can use this term for the ep method ? Thanks

Comment: The question should be "is there a different between a function defined using `val` and one defined using `def`", the closure characteristic has nothing to do there

Comment: Indeed, I know the difference between a function declared by val and a method declared by def. But my question is to know, if we can say of a method (defined by def) that it is closure since it uses free variables ? Thanks

Comment: It is not closure, but both can define/have associated closure

Comment: Sorry but I still have trouble understanding. Could you give me an example (with phi and ep) and the good vocabulary to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **function object** that captures free variables, and is said to be
*“closed”* over the variables visible at the time it is created is called **closure**. For example:

```
var foo = 10
val bar = (x:Int) => x+foo
```

Here, `foo` is **free variable** in function literal and hence the function literal is **open term**. As a result, val `bar` is a **closure** since function value (object) is created with open term `foo`.

Now, lets start with different between **val** and **def** in term of function definition.

> In scala, function is a value and you can assign it to variable.

When you define a function with **val**, you are defining it with a function literal as `val bar = (x:Int) => x+foo`, which **return a function object** and assign it as value to `bar`. In case of **val**, *the function value is evaluated as it is defined*. That means, function literal `(x:Int) => x+foo` is evaluated to function value with free variable `foo` and is stored in `bar` variable as **closure**.

```
//In the following snippet, a function literal is evaluated to object Function1 and assigned to val bar. 
scala> var foo = 10
foo: Int = 10

scala> val bar = (x: Int) => x + foo
bar: Int => Int = <function1>         //Function1 object is returned
```

Since, `bar` is a value and is evaluated as it is defined, it will always refer to same object in the memory whenever accessed.

```
scala> bar eq bar       //because both instance refer to same instance. 
res11: Boolean = true
```

On the other hand, you define a **method** with **def** and **method is not a function in Scala**. According to Scala language specification, [method do not have type in Scala hence it cannot be used as value](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#method-types).
For example, you cannot do as:

```
val bar = {def foo(x:Int): Int = x + 1 }
```

However, according to Specification, if method name is used as value, then Scala **implicitly converts** it to corresponding function type with [ETA Expression](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#eta-expansion). e.g. method `def a: Int` is converted as `a: => Int`. That means, every time you call method, it **returns a function value**.

```
scala> def foo():Int = 1
a: ()Int

scala> val bar:( ()=> Int) = foo
bar: () => Int = <function0>        //foo return Function0

//Note, val bar = foo, will assign the value returned by foo instead of returning function, so specify type.
```

Because of this, ***method can be used as function***. For example, when ever some method or function require a function type as argument, you can provide def method.

```
scala> val foo = (x:Int, double:Function1[Int, Int]) => double(x)
foo: (Int, Int => Int) => Int = <function2>

scala> def double(x:Int):Int = x * 2
double: (x: Int)Int

scala> foo(3, double)
res1: Int = 6
```

In addition, note that with method, you get a new function on every call.

```
scala> def double: Int => Int = _ * 2
double: Int => Int

scala> double eq double
res15: Boolean = false      //false because every time double refers to new instance and hence is not equal unlike val.
```

**Now, lets go to closure.** 
Both function literal defined with **val** and **def** method return function value (object). The function value (the object) that’s created at runtime from function literal is closure. On the other hand, a method is not a closure, but the function value you get from calling a method is a closure.

```
scala> var more = 1
more: Int = 1

scala> val foo = (x:Int) => x + more    // foo is clouser.
foo: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> def bar(x:Int):Int = x + more    // bar is not clouser.
bar: (x: Int)Int

scala> val barClouser : (Int => Int) = bar  // barClouser is clouser. 
barClouser: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val barValue = bar(3)    // bar is converted to clouser and then clouser value is evaluated and result is assigned to barValue variable. 
barValue: Int = 4   

scala> val fooValue = foo(3)    //foo value is evaluated and returned as value which is assigned to fooValue variable. 
fooValue: Int = 4
```

Comment: @Ra Ka Declaring a `def` doesn't create a closure as I demonstrated in my edited answer. `def` only get *converted* to closures when they are used as function values. When something is converted into something else it is not said to be something else.